# Oracle Increasing Database Block Size in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

I have this error :

```
01144. 00000 -  "File size (%s blocks) exceeds maximum of %s blocks"
*Cause:    Specified file size is larger than maximum allowable size value.
*Action:   Specify a smaller size.
```

when creating a TABLESPACE in

```
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
```

so I want to increasing Database Block Size, but I don't know how, and when I query the DB I got no results:

```
select distinct bytes/blocks from user_segments;
```

Comment: So you're trying to create a really big tablespace, with a single data file? Is it [a 'bigfile' tablespace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/managing-tablespaces.html#GUID-5C916922-25BD-4140-A76D-08F3C0E68426)? Including the statement that throws the exception, and the actual error, in your question might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you're trying to create a really big datafile, try creating the datafile as 100 MB at the beginning and then increase it. Please past the command you're using to create the tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

The default [database block size](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams041.htm#REFRN10031) can be setup only while creating a database. Anyway, manipulating of block size is an important and complex thing which affects not only datafiles, but also buffer cache, concurrency and so on. Don't try to play with it until you know what are you exactly doing and why.